Entête épreuve Maths
Bonsoir je suis un débutant et j'ai beaucoup des difficultés lorsqu'il me faut concevoir une entête de ce genre pour mon épreuve d'examen de mathématiques.
(Courtesy of translate.google.com:  Hello, I am a beginner and I have a lot of difficulty when I have to design a header of this kind for my mathematics exam.)

Welcome to TeX.SE. The language used on this site is English. If you edit your posting to translate your query into English, you will likely get a far more robust response from readers.

What Mico said.  But my Google translate of your question makes it sound like you're asking us to do all the work for you, which also doesn't get a good response.  If you're trying to adjust the header at the top of each page, read the documentation for the fancyhdr package.

Té otázce nerozímím. A pravděpodobně Vy nebudete rozumět mému komentáři. To mi připomíná Babylónskou věž.

Also, there is a French-speaking site: https://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/ (although I doubt that do-it-for-me question would fly there, too)

Apart from the language issue, you really should show what you tried so far. At least we need to know which document class and main packages you use in order to be able to help you here with the first steps. Without knowing anything about your document, it is very difficult to come up with a sensible solution. Maybe you can browse this site to find similar issues to help you get started.

And what we can do with OpTeX:
\def\cbox#1{\vtop{\kern0pt\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr#1\crcr}}}
\def\myheader{\readkv\myheaderset
   \hrule \bigskip
   \centerline{\rlap{\cbox{\kv{institution}\cr
                     \kv{service}\cr
                     \kv{department}\cr
                     \kv{teacher}\cr
                     \tt\kv{email}\cr
               }}\hfill
               \cbox{\picw=1.8cm\inspic{\kv{logo}.jpg}}%
               \hfill
               \llap{\cbox{\kv{year}\cr
                     \kv{class}\cr
                     \kv{duration}\cr
                     \kv{coefficient}\cr
               }}}
   \medskip
   \centerline{\hbox to.8\hsize{\hrulefill}}
}

\def\myheaderset{
  institution = \TeX{} University,
  service = Faculty of Typography,
  department = Department of Headers,
  logo = example-image-1x1,
  teacher = wipet,
  email = wipet@example.com,
  year = 2024/2025,
  class = beginners,
  duration = 6 hours,
  coefficient = 50\%
}

\myheader

\bye


The idea is to use a key-value interface that can be divided into two parts. With \examset you set the “fixed” keys, while you can fill in the other keys for a specific exam.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\examheader}{m}
 {% #1 is a set of key-value entries
  \gasam_entete:n {#1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\examset}{m}
 {% #1 is a set of key-value entries
  \keys_set:nn { gasam/entete } {#1}
 }

\keys_define:nn { gasam/entete }
 {
  institution .tl_set:N = \l_gasam_entete_institution_tl,
  service     .tl_set:N = \l_gasam_entete_service_tl,
  department  .tl_set:N = \l_gasam_entete_department_tl,
  teacher     .tl_set:N = \l_gasam_entete_teacher_tl,
  email       .tl_set:N = \l_gasam_entete_email_tl,
  year        .tl_set:N = \l_gasam_entete_year_tl,
  class       .tl_set:N = \l_gasam_entete_class_tl,
  duration    .tl_set:N = \l_gasam_entete_duration_tl,
  coefficient .tl_set:N = \l_gasam_entete_coefficient_tl,
  logo        .tl_set:N = \l_gasam_entete_logo_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \gasam_entete:n
 {
  \keys_set:nn { gasam/entete } {#1}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \linespread{1.2}\selectfont
  \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par\vspace{\medskipamount}
  \makebox[0pt][l]
   {
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \l_gasam_entete_institution_tl \\
    \l_gasam_entete_service_tl \\
    \l_gasam_entete_department_tl \\
    \l_gasam_entete_teacher_tl \\
    \texttt{\l_gasam_entete_email_tl}
    \end{tabular}
   }
  \hfill
  \raisebox{-3.5\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip]{\l_gasam_entete_logo_tl}}
  \hfill
  \makebox[0pt][r]
   {
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \l_gasam_entete_year_tl \\
    \l_gasam_entete_class_tl \\
    \l_gasam_entete_duration_tl \\
    \l_gasam_entete_coefficient_tl
    \end{tabular}
   }\par\vspace{\medskipamount}
   \hspace*{\fill}\rule{0.8\textwidth}{1pt}\hspace*{\fill}
  \end{minipage}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% the “fixed” parts
\examset{
  institution = \TeX{} University,
  service = Faculty of Typography,
  department = Department of Headers,
  logo = example-image-1x1,
}

\begin{document}

\examheader{
  teacher = egreg,
  email = egreg@example.com,
  year = 2024/2025,
  class = beginners,
  duration = 6 hours,
  coefficient = 50\%
}

\end{document}


